# can someone explain this rounding behaviour

Tags: c#, rounding

I dont understand why it behaves like this

```
a = "1,00"
IFormatProvider numberlanguagestyle = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
pricetopay = (int)decimal.Parse(a, numberlanguagestyle);
Console.writeline(pricetopay)
```

this outputs **100**

while

```
a = "1"
IFormatProvider numberlanguagestyle = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
pricetopay = (int)decimal.Parse(a, numberlanguagestyle);
Console.writeline(pricetopay)
```

this outputs **1**

Now this works fine in my build of vs2010, but we have different programmers using different languages and we got into discussions about rounding errors and stuff like that
While above code works correct in our app, i wondered why it behaves like that.

Comment: Could be that the en-US culture uses a period and not a comma for decimal placement

Comment: This isn't a rounding issue.  It's a culture issue.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: The problem is not in rounding, but in mismatch in what the code uses as decimal point (`,`) and what en-US culture uses as decimal point (`.`)

Comment: If you want that text converted "correctly" you should do the string to decimal conversion using the culture that the number is stored in.  Then when you display the number you can display it using a different culture.

Comment: I think the answer to the actual question can now safely be assumed to be "yes" :)

Comment: It's been 4-5 minutes, since I am looking at this question and I don't really get why people keep repeating the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `en-US` culture, the comma is a thousands-separator, so it is basically ignored. `"1,00"` is therefore interpeted as `"100"`, which is, well, 100.

Comment: Aha that explains some weird behaviour we saw. We are Dutch and have the "," as decimal point. but where coding for english machines.
I didnt think of it asuming seperation was the same

Answer (score 4):

That is because `,` is used as number group separator, not as decimal point. Typically you would use this to group thousands, like `1,000,000` for one million. In the `en-US` culture you need to use `.` as decimal point.

Comment: Well, not just *currency* - a general grouping separator.

Comment: Yeah, that was a brain fart, I was talking about currency here before I wrote up the answer and the word snuck into the answer as well. Context switching is a bi***.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your question (since I don't see what it has to do with rounding), but in the US the decimal separator is `"."`, not `","`, so the parser is (correctly) interpreting `1,00` as 100.